# How to change the port when calling sqlcmd

Tags: sql, sqlcmd

I have this command

```
sqlcmd.exe -E -i "C:\joe-db-scripts\joe-db-tasks.Install.sql"
```

and I need to add the specific non-standard port of 32001. How do I do that? I was thinking of some flag like `-p` or something but I don't know the syntax.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

According to [this MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms188247(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#to-connect-using-tcpip), you'd use `-S tcp:servername,32001`.

Comment: MSDN conveniently leaves out the fact that you need to put quotes around the server name and port: `-S "servername,32001"`.

Comment: RE a 2020 proposed edit: This answer was from 2011, and may provide a solution for a version that could still be in use in somewhere. It may be preferable to leave a comment here with the current version's info, and/or add a new answer, if the syntax has changed noticebly. There is a meta topic on this particular issue. It's not always preferable to edit/update all old posts when languages change. Much knowledge here could get lost, and make older systems impossible to debug if this legacy info is lost completely. I am not familiar enough to judge in this case, so I SKIP-ped it in review.

Comment: To be sure here is the info @duderoot suggested:  According to [this MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms188247(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#to-connect-using-tcpip), you'd use `-S tcp:servername,32001`.

Comment: Here was the previous info, from May 2011: According to this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx), you'd use `-S servername,32001`. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

That's it: [How to Connect to the Database Engine using sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188247%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). Something like this:

```
sqlcmd -S ComputerA,1691
```

Answer (score 2):

Following solution is working for me in SQL Server 2008 and above.

```
sqlcmd -S "hostname or IP,port number" -U SA -P password
```

Answer (score 0):

Mayo/23/2022, works

> sqlcmd -S "hostname or IP,port number"

SQL Express 2019 from linux ubuntu client connecting to sql express on windows server