# Microsoft SQL Server Resolution Protocol (SSRP) - how to specify a database host?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

When connecting to SQL Server through a proxy, you have to match the DNS name to the IP address of your proxy in `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\HOSTS` or `/etc/hosts`. It seems to be due to SSRP:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff420676(v=sql.105).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc219703.aspx

This is mainly an issue on Azure SQL databases because of the underlying proxying and virtualization used.

Is there a way to specify the hostname to use in the database client or SQL Server Management Studio without adding a `HOSTS` file entry?

Comment: Specifying a port in `sqlcmd`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099923/how-to-change-the-port-when-calling-sqlcmd

Comment: Using `haproxy` or IP tables for proxying connections: https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2016/11/load-balancing-microsoft-sql-server-with-haproxy/ and https://serverfault.com/questions/908076/ms-sql-port-forwarding-with-ip-tables